# Purge varnish cache with multiple backends

Tags: caching, varnish

I have a varnish cache, behind an nginx ssl termination node, that is routing to two different backends(both running wordpress), based on the url.  "/" is routed to serverA and "/about/" is routed to serverB.

If I first curl locally `curl http://127.0.0.1/`, to set the cache, and then  `curl -X PURGE http://127.0.0.1/`, it clears the cache.

If I hit it from our nginx ssl termination server, and then try to clear the cache with the same curl command, it doesn't clear the cached item created by passing through the nginx server.

## *vcl file:*

```
# Based off of https://gist.github.com/matthewjackowski/062be03b41a68edbadfc

# Marker to tell the VCL compiler that this VCL has been adapted to the
# new 4.0 format.
vcl 4.0;
import directors;

# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
    .host = "serverA";
    .port = "80";
    .connect_timeout = 600s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 600s;
    .max_connections = 800;
}

backend bedrock {
    .host = "serverB";
    .port = "80";
    .connect_timeout = 600s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 600s;
    .max_connections = 800;
}

# Only allow purging from specific IPs
acl purge {
    "localhost";
    "127.0.0.1";
}

# This function is used when a request is send by a HTTP client (Browser) 
sub vcl_recv {
    # Normalize the header, remove the port (in case you're testing this on various TCP ports)
    set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
    set req.backend_hint = default;

    # Unset headers that might cause us to cache duplicate infos
    unset req.http.Accept-Language;
    unset req.http.User-Agent;
    set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "https";

    if (req.url == "/") {
        set req.backend_hint = bedrock;
    }

    # Allow purging from ACL
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        # If not allowed then a error 405 is returned
        if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
            return(synth(405, "This IP is not allowed to send PURGE requests."));
        }    
        # If allowed, do a cache_lookup -> vlc_hit() or vlc_miss()
        return (purge);
    }

    # drop cookies and params from static assets
    if (req.url ~ "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|swf|ttf|css|js|flv|mp3|mp4|pdf|ico|png)(\?.*|)$") {
        unset req.http.cookie;
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?.*$", "");
    }

    # drop tracking params, only needed on the frontend.
    if (req.url ~ "\?(utm_(campaign|medium|source|term)|adParams|client|cx|eid|fbid|feed|ref(id|src)?|v(er|iew))=") {
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?.*$", "");
    }

    # pass wp-admin urls
    if (req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)" || req.url ~ "preview=true" || req.url ~ "xmlrpc.php") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # pass wp-admin cookies
    if (req.http.cookie) {
        if (req.http.cookie ~ "(wordpress_|wp-settings-)") {
            return(pass);
        } else {
            unset req.http.cookie;
        }
    }
}

# Drop any cookies Wordpress tries to send back to the client.
sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Remove some headers we never want to see
    unset beresp.http.Server;
    unset beresp.http.X-Powered-By;
    # This function is used when a request is sent by our backend (Nginx server)
    if (bereq.http.Cookie ~ "(UserID|_session)") {
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Got Session";
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (deliver);

    } elsif (beresp.ttl <= 0s) {
        # Varnish determined the object was not cacheable
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Not Cacheable";

    } elsif (beresp.http.set-cookie) {
        # You don't wish to cache content for logged in users
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Set-Cookie";
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (deliver);

    } elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        # You are respecting the Cache-Control=private header from the backend
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Cache-Control=private";
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (deliver);

    } else {
        # Varnish determined the object was cacheable
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "YES";
        # Remove Expires from backend, it's not long enough
        unset beresp.http.expires;
        # Set the clients TTL on this object
        set beresp.http.cache-control = "max-age=900";
        # Set how long Varnish will keep it
        set beresp.ttl = 1d;
    }

    if ( (!(bereq.url ~ "((wp/)?wp-(login|admin)|login)")) || (bereq.method == "GET") ) {
        set beresp.http.X-UnsetCookies = "TRUE";
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
        set beresp.ttl = 1h;
    }

    if (bereq.url ~ "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|swf|ttf|css|js|flv|mp3|mp4|pdf|ico|png)(\?.*|)$") {
        set beresp.ttl = 1d;
    }

}

# The routine when we deliver the HTTP request to the user
# Last chance to modify headers that are sent to the client
sub vcl_deliver {
    if (obj.hits > 0) { 
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "cached";
    } else {
        set resp.http.x-Cache = "uncached";
    }

    # Remove some headers: PHP version
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
    # Remove some headers: Apache version & OS
    unset resp.http.Server;
    # Remove some headers: Varnish
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
}
```

## *varnishlog output when cacheing page*

```
*   << BeReq    >> 3         
-   Begin          bereq 2 fetch
-   Timestamp      Start: 1488390891.742004 0.000000 0.000000
-   BereqMethod    GET
-   BereqURL       /
-   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.0
-   BereqHeader    X-Prerender-Token: qUcOM8XD5dRKUvlnCaMx
-   BereqHeader    X-Real-IP: 10.224.20.1
-   BereqHeader    Host: ssl-sermination-domain.com
-   BereqHeader    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   BereqHeader    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
-   BereqHeader    DNT: 1
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 10.224.20.146
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
-   BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 3
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   BackendOpen    20 boot.bedrock 10.240.0.4 80 10.224.20.148 39350
-   BackendStart   10.240.0.4 80
-   Timestamp      Bereq: 1488390891.743281 0.001276 0.001276
-   Timestamp      Beresp: 1488390891.863164 0.121160 0.119883
-   BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
-   BerespStatus   200
-   BerespReason   OK
-   BerespHeader   Date: Wed, 01 Mar 2017 17:54:51 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
-   BerespHeader   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21
-   BerespHeader   Link: <https://ssl-sermination-domain.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
-   BerespHeader   Link: <https://ssl-sermination-domain.com/>; rel=shortlink
-   BerespHeader   Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   BerespHeader   Content-Encoding: gzip
-   BerespHeader   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
-   BerespHeader   Cache-Control: Public
-   BerespHeader   Max-Age: 600
-   BerespHeader   Content-Length: 6396
-   BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
-   TTL            RFC 120 10 -1 1488390892 1488390892 1488390891 0 0
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
-   BerespUnset    Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
-   BerespUnset    X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21
-   BerespHeader   X-Cacheable: YES
-   BerespUnset    Cache-Control: Public
-   BerespHeader   cache-control: max-age=900
-   TTL            VCL 86400 10 0 1488390892
-   BerespHeader   X-UnsetCookies: TRUE
-   TTL            VCL 3600 10 0 1488390892
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Storage        malloc s0
-   ObjProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ObjStatus      200
-   ObjReason      OK
-   ObjHeader      Date: Wed, 01 Mar 2017 17:54:51 GMT
-   ObjHeader      Link: <https://ssl-sermination-domain.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
-   ObjHeader      Link: <https://ssl-sermination-domain.com/>; rel=shortlink
-   ObjHeader      Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   ObjHeader      Content-Encoding: gzip
-   ObjHeader      Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
-   ObjHeader      Max-Age: 600
-   ObjHeader      Content-Length: 6396
-   ObjHeader      Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
-   ObjHeader      X-Cacheable: YES
-   ObjHeader      cache-control: max-age=900
-   ObjHeader      X-UnsetCookies: TRUE
-   Fetch_Body     3 length stream
-   Gzip           u F - 6396 27271 80 80 51104
-   BackendReuse   20 boot.bedrock
-   Timestamp      BerespBody: 1488390891.863519 0.121514 0.000355
-   Length         6396
-   BereqAcct      331 0 331 435 6396 6831
-   End            

*   << Request  >> 2         
-   Begin          req 1 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1488390891.741888 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1488390891.741888 0.000000 0.000000
-   ReqStart       10.224.20.146 33370
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.0
-   ReqHeader      X-Prerender-Token: qUcOM8XD5dRKUvlnCaMx
-   ReqHeader      X-Real-IP: 10.224.20.1
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 10.224.20.1
-   ReqHeader      Host: ssl-sermination-domain.com
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqHeader      Connection: close
-   ReqHeader      Cache-Control: max-age=0
-   ReqHeader      Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
-   ReqHeader      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
-   ReqHeader      DNT: 1
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: __qca=P0-1762908153-1488362085426; _mkto_trk=id:503-BAR-730&token:_mch-ssl-termination.com-1488362085634-71558; calltrk_referrer=direct;     calltrk_landing=https%3A//www.ssl-termination.com/about/; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1488387324154r0.4330785754032478; op
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: 10.224.20.1
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 10.224.20.1, 10.224.20.146
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: 10.224.20.1, 10.224.20.146
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 10.224.20.146
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
-   ReqUnset       User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqUnset       Cookie: __qca=P0-1762908153-1488362085426; _mkto_trk=id:503-BAR-730&token:_mch-ssl-termination.com-1488362085634-71558; calltrk_referrer=direct;     calltrk_landing=https%3A//www.ssl-termination.com/about/; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1488387324154r0.4330785754032478; op
-   VCL_return     hash
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 3 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1488390891.863387 0.121500 0.121500
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     200
-   RespReason     OK
-   RespHeader     Date: Wed, 01 Mar 2017 17:54:51 GMT
-   RespHeader     Link: <https://ssl-sermination-domain.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
-   RespHeader     Link: <https://ssl-sermination-domain.com/>; rel=shortlink
-   RespHeader     Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   RespHeader     Content-Encoding: gzip
-   RespHeader     Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
-   RespHeader     Max-Age: 600
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 6396
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
-   RespHeader     X-Cacheable: YES
-   RespHeader     cache-control: max-age=900
-   RespHeader     X-UnsetCookies: TRUE
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 2
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespHeader     x-Cache: uncached
-   RespUnset      X-Varnish: 2
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1488390891.863412 0.121524 0.000025
-   RespHeader     Accept-Ranges: bytes
-   Debug          "RES_MODE 2"
-   RespHeader     Connection: close
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1488390891.863608 0.121720 0.000196
-   ReqAcct        1089 0 1089 501 6396 6897
-   End            

*   << Session  >> 1         
-   Begin          sess 0 HTTP/1
-   SessOpen       10.224.20.146 33370 0.0.0.0:8081 10.224.20.148 8081 1488390891.741828 14
-   Link           req 2 rxreq
-   SessClose      RESP_CLOSE 0.122
-   End
```

## *varnishlog when purging*:

```
*   << Request  >> 98364     
-   Begin          req 98363 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1488390373.620924 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1488390373.620924 0.000000 0.000000
-   ReqStart       127.0.0.1 56100
-   ReqMethod      PURGE
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
-   ReqHeader      Host: 127.0.0.1:8081
-   ReqHeader      Accept: */*
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1
-   ReqUnset       User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   VCL_acl        MATCH purge "localhost"
-   VCL_return     purge
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       PURGE
-   VCL_return     synth
-   Timestamp      Process: 1488390373.620977 0.000052 0.000052
-   RespHeader     Date: Wed, 01 Mar 2017 17:46:13 GMT
-   RespHeader     Server: Varnish
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 98364
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     200
-   RespReason     OK
-   RespReason     Purged
-   VCL_call       SYNTH
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-   RespHeader     Retry-After: 5
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 240
-   Storage        malloc Transient
-   RespHeader     Accept-Ranges: bytes
-   Debug          "RES_MODE 2"
-   RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1488390373.621082 0.000158 0.000106
-   ReqAcct        80 0 80 218 240 458
-   End            

*   << Session  >> 98363     
-   Begin          sess 0 HTTP/1
-   SessOpen       127.0.0.1 56100 0.0.0.0:8081 127.0.0.1 8081 1488390373.620850 18
-   Link           req 98364 rxreq
-   SessClose      REM_CLOSE 0.000
-   End
```

### Edit:

I believe that I need a different purge command, because if I ssh into the varnish box and run the following:

1. curl the url locally (uncached)
2. curl the url locally (cached)
3. curl purge again locally
4. curl the url locally (uncached)
5. curl the url locally (cached)

It works as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the default [vcl_hash](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/vcl-hashing.html) and figured it out.  I need to send the Host header and it busts the cache properly.

`curl -X PURGE http://127.0.0.1:8081/ -H "Host: ssl-termination-domain.com"`